# Long-press = Capitalize

Tags: autohotkey, capitalization

**Intended Hotkey Function**: Capitalize character if key pressed longer than 0.2s

**Occurring Problem**: When typing "*vbnm*" in a row in a fast manner (which means I am pressing a the next key while still holding down the previous one) then AHK outputs just x-times the key that was pressed first, resulting here in "*vvvv*".

That is the code. Please help me out (y) :-)

```
$y::
$x::
$c::
$v::
$b::
$n::
$m::
    key := SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2)  
    ;MsgBox, %key% ;it recognizes/shows all keys pressed correctly,
    ;but in the end it prints just x-times the key that was pressed first
    ;whereby x is the number of keys pressed very quickly in a row

    KeyWait, %key%, T0.2 ;Long press = capitalize
    If ErrorLevel
        SendInput +%key%    
    Else
        SendInput %key%         
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$y:: 
$x::  
$c::
$v::
$b::
$n::
$m::keyFunc(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2))

keyFunc(key) {   
    KeyWait, %key%, T0.3 ;Long press = capitalize
    SendInput % ErrorLevel ? Format("{:U}", key) : key  
Return
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear your answer! Your script makes a difference. Typing "vbnm" does not result into "vvvv" anymore, but into "mnbv", so it send each character but just in the wrong order. So putting the code inside a separate function was the solution. 
Adding critical puts the characters back into order, and now it seems to work fine. 
Two things are still not quite satisfying: First, Writing german umlaute, special keys or numbers, but I solved it. Second, press a key too long and it will output not only the capitalized one, but also the normal one too, e.g."Oo".

Answer (score 2):

So finally this code seems to work, beside the little inconvenience when holding the key much too long, resulting in e.g. "Oo".

```
;For normal characters ......
$x::
$c::
$v::
$b::
$n::
$m::keyFunc(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2))
keyFunc(key) {   
    Critical
    KeyWait, %key%, T0.3 ;Long press = capitalize
    SendInput % ErrorLevel ? Format("{:U}", key) : key  
Return 
}

;For special characters ......
$2::
$3::
$4::
$5::
$6::
$7::
$8::
$9::
$sc01A:: ;ü
$sc027:: ;ö
$sc028:: ;ä
$sc00C:: ;ß
$sc033:: ;,
$sc034:: ;. 
$sc035:: ;-
$sc01B:: ;+
$sc02B:: ;#
$sc00D::  keyFunc2(SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 2))
keyFunc2(key) {
    Critical  
    KeyWait, %key%, T0.3 ;Long press = capitalize   
    If ErrorLevel
        SendInput +{%key%}
    Else
        SendInput {%key%}
Return
}
```

Comment: Update: don't do it. It will never work as expected.